# Redirect stdout and stderr to a file and also to console in linux

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-14.04

I can redirect stdout and stderr to a file like below

```
some_command.sh >> file.txt 2>&1
```

Can someone let me know how can I redirect stdout and stderr to a file and also to console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tee` command can help you out. It reads from standard input and writes to standard output and files.

So the following command will do:

```
some_command.sh 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

Manpage: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html